# SQL Server - LIKE Operator Works When Searching Partial String But Not Whole String

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, sql-like

I am experiencing an issue with my SQL Server database that, truthfully, I'm unsure how to even describe. Therefore, I will try to demonstrate it, as best I can.

I have a table containing several rows where the value in the `[Meter Name]` column is

```
Electric Meter #140002054 Acct.2013147 House, south mall service &&parking lot
```

Now, when I run the following query, I get exactly the result I would expect.

```
select distinct [Meter Name] 
from Last_PM_Export
where [Meter Name] like 'Electric Meter #140002054 Acct.2013147 House, south mall service%'
```

Note that I am using a % wildcard, cutting off the search pattern immediately after the word "service". I get the following result.

[Expected result using partial string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cw2G2.png)

Again, this is exactly what I would expect. No problem.

Now, observe what happens when I extend the pattern to include the space that comes immediately after the word "service".

```
select distinct [Meter Name] 
from Last_PM_Export
where [Meter Name] like 'Electric Meter #140002054 Acct.2013147 House, south mall service %'
```

[Unexpected result using partial string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjorE.png)

As you can see, the query returns no results. I have also tried querying for the entire string, as is, copied directly out of the table.

```
select distinct [Meter Name] 
from Last_PM_Export
where [Meter Name] like 'Electric Meter #140002054 Acct.2013147 House, south mall service &&parking lot'
```

The result is the same as the query immediately above. No results.

I cannot think of any reason this should be happening. It flies in the face of how I understand the `LIKE` operator to work. I've consulted with our in-office IT person, and he agrees that this is unusual.

Again, I know this isn't a very good description of the problem, but hopefully the demonstration will suffice. Also, my apologies for not being able to share the table or the database more fully, but I cannot do so for reasons of confidentiality.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe that blank space after "service" isn't a blank space.

Comment: Get a hex editor to check out what the space and two &'s are.  There is a chance all three are control characters.  I get that at work a lot when data operators copy and paste addresses into our database.

Comment: You could look at the data on the page and check that it is actually a ' ' after 'service'

Comment: Did you **copy'n'paste** the text above (directly out of the result view into this message)?

Comment: I cannot repoduce it... What is the datatype of this column (`varchar`, `nvarchar`, other)? Is there a strange collation? I remember something with a silly issue with a doubled *A* meaning a different letter in a scandinavian language...

Comment: @abraxascarab Using an online hex editor, I have confirmed that the hexadecimal codes for the space and the &'s are 20 and 26, respectively.  I believe this is correct.

Comment: @Shnugo The data type of this column is varchar(255).  According to the table properties, the collation is the <database default>, which, according to the database properties, is **SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer, but to much for a comment... Would you please confirm, that this an exact scenario of your issue? As you can easily check out, both `SELECT`s come back with the right rows...

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE([Meter Name] VARCHAR(1000));
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES('Electric Meter #140002054 Acct.2013147 House, south mall service &&parking lot')
                         ,('Electric Meter #140002054 Acct.2013147 House, south mall service &&some other')
                         ,('different');
```

--Without a blank

```
SELECT * FROM @mockup 
where [Meter Name] like 'Electric Meter #140002054 Acct.2013147 House, south mall service%';
```

--With blank

```
SELECT * FROM @mockup 
where [Meter Name] like 'Electric Meter #140002054 Acct.2013147 House, south mall service %';
```

Might be there is something more, you reduced for brevity? Are you able to change the above *mock-up* in order to make your issue reproduceable?

Comment: This was helpful, and provided some insight into the source of the issue.  I was not able to reproduce the issue using the mock-up table, when simply copying the value over from a query result.  However, I investigated the source of the data that went into the table, a CSV file.  It turns out that the source cells contain a carriage return.  I suspect that when the data was imported, so was the carriage return.  However, it is hidden within the database.  When I pasted from the CSV cell into your mock-up I was able to reproduce the issue.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @J.P.Brown Glad to help you! The *grid-view* will ommit line breaks. You might swith to *output-to-text*... And yes: Such issues let you doubt your own mind :-D